# How can I convert "[nan,1,2,3]" string to list [nan,1,2,3]?

Tags: python, string, list

How can I convert `"[nan,1,2,3]"` string to list `[nan,1,2,3]`?

If I use

```
    from ast import literal_eval

    literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
```

I get

```
    [1, 2, 3]
```

But if i try to convert the string with a `nan` in it, i get the following error occurred:

```
    File "<unknown>", line 1
        [nan  1  2  3
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The input `[nan  1  2  3` does not even have commas in it, you can't use `literal_eval` with it.

Comment: `eval `can do this

Comment: @DustyPosa eval does it but very bad practice

Comment: @DustyPosa i think in general `eval` should be avoided, as you could inject ANY code into it. You might get away with it if it's just for you, but in general there are typically better and more robust solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `np.fromstring`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

lst = '[nan  1  2  3]'
print(np.fromstring(lst.strip("[]"), sep=' '))
#-->[nan  1.  2.  3.]
```

Comment: very elegant solution. I'd say this is the most pythonic, especially with the `.strip("[]")` that is very explicit for anyone.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace the `NaN` by `None` which *is* valid python, and then use `literal_eval`:

```
s = "[nan,1,2,3]"

literal_eval(s.replace('nan', 'None'))
# [None, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is the soluation if you want to convert strings of complex structures such as list of tuples with `nan`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.fromstring`:

```
>>> s = '[nan, 1, 2, 3]'
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.fromstring(s[1:-1], sep=', ')
>>> a
array([ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.])
>>>
```

Comment: Is this a real NaN or the string 'nan'? I would assume OP wants `np.nan`.

Comment: @BramVanroy Real nan

Comment: that's the beauty of the `fromstring` method, it creates a numpy array in which all values have the same datatype. So you can't mix float numbers with strings even if you wanted to; they are all floats even the nan.

Comment: @Magellan88 True

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use numpy, you can use the implicit type conversion for floats (note that with integers, there is no nan)

```
import numpy as np    
a = "[nan 1 2 3]"
np.array(a[1:-1].split(), dtype="f")
#array([nan,  1.,  2.,  3.], dtype=float32)
```